# How to insert an integer with nextval function in an multirow insert in pg-promise

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

Is it possible to use the nextval function in a pg-promise multirow insert?
I have a database (that I sadly can't change) where the id has to be inserted via the client like this:

```
INSERT INTO some_object (object_id, object_name)
VALUES (nextval('some_object_seq'), ${object_name})
RETURNING object_id;
```

This works fine for one insert. But now I have to insert multiple rows at once and tried pgp.helpers.insert:

```
const cs = pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['object_id', 'object_name'], { table });
const query = pgp.helpers.insert(values, cs)  + 'RETURNING object_id';
database.many(query).then(data => {
  return data
}).catch(error => {
  logger.error(error, query);
});
```

Is there any way to use nextval('some_object_seq') in this scenario? Sadly I can't change the default value of the id column in the table definition.

Comment: Are you sure the `object_id` column doesn't have the sequence as a `DEFAULT` already?

Comment: You can give your `ColumnSet` a [`def`ault expression for the `object_id` column](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.ColumnConfig)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that no DEFAULT is set and I can't change that. I tried { name: "object_id", def: "nextval('some_object_seq')" } but the nextval is then send as a string and not recognised as a function.

Comment: Ah I forgot to add this: mod: '^', thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your column should be defined as this:

```js
{
    name: `object_id`,
    init: () => `nextval('some_object_seq')`,
    mod: `:raw`
}
```

As opposed to the answer by @baal, you do not need to use `def`, because you are not providing a default value, rather a complete override for the value, which is what `init` for.

And it can be used within upsert queries too.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Will try that and accept this as the answer then!

Answer (score 1):

As Bergi wrote, it is possible to add a default expression to the column set like this:

```
const cs = pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(
        [{
            name: "object_id",
            // setting the DEFAULT value for this column
            def: "nextval('some_object_seq')", 
            // use raw-text modifier to inject string directly
            mod: "^",
        }, 'object_name'], { table });
```

Comment: Only downside of this solution that shouldn't be forgotten: this columnset can't be used for an `update`

Comment: @Bergi Yes, but it can be used with upsert queries.